# How to encapsulate Play template parts in a separate module?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Play application consisting of the following to modules:

1. `angular`: encapsulates all AngularJS stuff
2. `frontend`: customer faced stuff

The `angular` module has a webjar dependency defined in the `build.sbt` file. In addition, I have there the following HTML file inside the `views` directory:

```
@(webJarAssets: WebJarAssets)

<script src="@angular.controllers.routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("jquery.js"))"></script>
<script src="@angular.controllers.routes.WebJarAssets.at(webJarAssets.locate("angularjs.js"))"></script>
```

My controller looks like this:

```
package angular.controllers

import javax.inject._

import play.api.mvc._

@Singleton
class TestController @Inject() (webJarAssets: WebJarAssets) extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(angular.views.html.test(webJarAssets))
  }

}
```

So far so good, when accessing the corresponding route, everything renders fine. However, that's not how I want to use this module.

In my `frontend` module I have a template named `main.scala.html` which looks like this:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        @* Here's where we render the page title `String`. *@
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.versioned("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.versioned("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @content
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to include the `angular` module template, which encapsulates the script tags, after `@content`. In addition, I want to make this optional so that I can pass a specific argument in order to activate the script inclusion. How can I make this work?